# How to make apt-get working in Oracle Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, wine

I have tried to install Wine on to my Oracle Linux by using `apt-get install wine`, but it didn't work.

I have tried this as normal user but it was showing this error:

> bash: apt-get: command not found.

I also tried as `root` with `sudo apt-get install wine`. It, too, throws an error:

> ksai is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

I added that user to `sudoers` using `visudo` as follows:

```
ksai  ALL=(ALL) ALL**
```

It was of no use. How to make the installation work?

Comment: You need to install apt-get first.

Answer (score 6):

Oracle Linux doesn't use `apt`(apt is for debian or debian forks), it uses `yum` or `dnf` because yum is *deprecated*(**added note in the botton**).

**to install wine you should use the folowing command:**

How to install wine using [Yellowdog Updater Modified](http://linux.die.net/man/8/yum):

```
yum install wine
```

How to install wine using [dnf](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/DNF)

```
dnf install wine
```

Documentation about how to install packages in [Oracle Linux](https://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/installing-software-packages)

> **NOTE about `dnf`:**  i've only tested in Fedora 22, i heard `dnf` still **experimental** and is not crossing another distributions.

Answer (score 1):

Different Linux distributions different ways to install new packages.
'apt-get' is a command used by the [Advanced Packaging Tool (APT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool) mostly used by Debian and its derivatives.

Oracle Linux seems to use the [RPM Package Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPM_Package_Manager), so you have to use that to install wine.

https://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/installing-software-packages might be helpful.